# If every linear operator on $X$ is bounded then is $\dim X<\infty$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, linear-transformations

I have started learning *Functional Analysis*:

I have encountered a theorem which states that if

> If $X(NLS)$  is finite dimensional then every linear operator on $X$ is bounded.

Is the converse true?i.e if every linear operator on $X$ is bounded then is $\dim X<\infty$?

In order to show this ;Proceed by contradiction; suppose that $\dim X=\infty$ I want to show that there exits an unbounded linear operator on $X$.Let $X$ have a Hamel Basis say $(e_n)$,then any $x\in X$ can be expressed uniquely as $x=\sum_{k=1}^n c_ie_i$.

How should I define $f(x)$ now to get $f(x)$ unbounded?Any hints will be helpful.
Please ensure to give some hints why it should be unbounded
?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that $X$ is just a normed linear space.

You probably shouldn’t index your Hamel basis by $n$, as it does not need to be countable. Instead, take a countable family $(e_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of linearly independent elements, let $U = \langle e_n \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \rangle$ and let $V$ be a direct complement of $U$, i.e. $X = U \oplus V$. We can assume w.l.og. that $\|e_n\| = 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Now consider the linear map $\phi \colon X \to X$ defined by $\phi(e_n) = n e_1$ and $\phi|_V = 0$. Then for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $\|\phi(e_n)\| = n$ with $\|e_n\| = 1$, so $\phi$ is not bounded.

Comment: can't I just simply  use that if $\{e_i:i\in I\}$ is a basis of $X$ and then define $f:X\to X$ by $f(e_i)=i$; it will be great if you could verify this

Comment: If the codomain of $f$ is supposed to be $X$, then this you would only make sense if $i \in X$ for every $i \in I$, i.e. if $I \subseteq X$. For this to be a counterexample you would then need that $I$ is unbounded in $X$. But I think that in general it would be rather confusing to index a basis of $X$ by some subset of $X$ (as long as this doesn’t arise in some natural way).

Comment: Thank you one more question if codomain is $Y$ then how should I change the functional

Comment: If $Y = 0$ then every linear map $X \to Y$ is continuous. If $Y \neq 0$ then take some non-zero $y \in Y$ and consider $\psi \colon X \to Y$ defined by $\psi(e_n) = ny$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\psi|_V = 0$. (The unifying idea behind these counterexamples is to find some discontinuous linear functional $f \colon X \to \mathbb{K}$, where $\mathbb{K}$ denotes the ground field, and then embedd $\mathbb{K}$ into $Y$ by choosing some non-zero vector $y \in Y$ and take $\mathbb{K} \to Y$, $\lambda \mapsto \lambda y$. Here I chose $f$ as $f(e_n) = n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $f|_V = 0$.)

Comment: thank you very much; can you suggest some books in "functional analysis"

Comment: Sadly I don’t know any books on functional analysis.

Comment: @Learnmore 1) Taylor, Lay. Introduction to Functional Analysis. 2) Rudin. Functional Analysis. 3) Meise, Vogt. Introduction to Functional Analysis. 4) Kothe. Topological Vector Spaces (I). 5) Conway. A Course in Functional Analysis. 6) Lax. Functional Analysis.